# Hibernate Criteria API

Tags: hibernate, api, search, criteria

I need to do a search which involves navigating down to the child elements and then back up to the root/parent. How do I do such a thing using the Criteria API?

As an example I have:

```
Criteria crit = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()
    .createCriteria(TherapistImpl.class);
```

Now I need to go to the User class to get the address which is associated with the user ( a set of Addresses):

```
crit.createCriteria("user")
    .createCriteria("addresses")
    .add(Restrictions.eq("postcode", postCode));
```

But now I've done this, I need to go back up to get the other one-to-many associations from the parent class TherapyImpl e.g.

```
crit.createCriteria("therapyProvisions")
    .add(Restrictions.eq("type", searchByValueSelected));
```

But hibernate thinks this is referring to the User criteria that we chained and created earlier.

So do I create multiple criterias?? Is there a way of navigating back up the tree etc?

thanks for your comments
Paul

Answer (score 1):

Rather than creating a sub-`Criteria` for the `user` association, create an alias for it:

```
crit.createAlias("user", "userAlias");
crit.add(Restrictions.eq("userAlias.addresses.postcode", postCode);
```

(You might need to create a sub-alias for `addresses`.)

Then, do the same for `therapyProvisions`:

```
crit.createAlias("therapyProvisions", "therapyProvisionsAlias");
crit.add(Restrictions.eq("therapyProvisionsAlias.type", searchByValueSelected);
```

Now you'll have inner joins all around.